# python pandas groupby filter

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

Concretely, say I have a DataFrame like this:

```
appid  mac_id  count

1      a        1 

2      b        1

2      c        1

3      d        1

3      e        1
```

And I also have a :

```
mac_list = ['b', 'd', 'e']
```

I want to group this data frame on appid and for every group filter `mac_id` if it's in `mac_list`. Last, sum(count) for every group.

for this DataFrame the result is:

```
appid   count

1         0

2         1

3         2
```

How can I do this with Pandas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"appid": [1,2,2,3,3], "mac_id": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], "count": [1,1,1,1,1]})
>>> summer = lambda x: x[x["mac_id"].isin(mac_list)].sum()
>>> df.groupby("appid").apply(summer)["count"]
  18 
appid
1        0
2        1
3        2
Name: count, dtype: object
```